# How to check if a generic property exists on a generic object <T> typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am converting a codebase from Javascript to Typescript and having trouble with this one function. I am getting a typescript error on line `const valueAtKey = item[key]` saying `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)`

I thought I could escape the error by checking if the property exists in T but even after wrapping in `if (key in item)` the error is not going away.

```
export const convertArrayToDict = <T extends object>(arr: Array<T>, key: string): Record<string, T> => {
    const dict: Record<string, T> = {}
    // Iterate over each item, and add to new object using the value of the key as the new key
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (key in item) {
            const valueAtKey = item[key]
            if (valueAtKey && !dict[valueAtKey]) {
                dict[valueAtKey] = item
            }
        }
    }
    return dict
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like `arr` is an array of keyed objects where each object has string keys and string values.  If that is the case, then all you need to do is replace:

```
<T extends object>
```

with:

```
<T extends Record<string, string>>
```

or if some object values might be undefined:

```
<T extends Record<string, string | undefined>
```

This gives typescript more information about the array elements then just saying that they extend `object`.  Specifically, the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type adds a string index which causes your error to go away.

Comment: The Record<string, string> is actually supposed to be Record<string, string | number | object | []).